# SSD detected on my Windows but not detected on BIOS boot

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

My Notebook had problem with boot priority.
So I have HDD on main port and I just added SSD for my second port (replace my CD/DVD drive).
I had problem with my main port so i cant replace it for SSD.
my SSD : Samsung 850 EVO and I already migrate it using samsung Migration.
So i had 2 windows on my HDD and my SSD.
but windows still run on my HDD not my SSD.
I try change some setting on boot priority..
but i dont see my SSD on there...

NB:

1. SATA setting = AHCI
2. Main HDD = HDD (WD something),
   SATA ODD = my SSD (Samsung SSD)
3. I cant upgrade my BIOS (I think it's already up to date) (Im using Dell N4110 Inspiron and BIOS ver A12)
4. I already unplug my main HDD but it cant boot so i can't run windows on my SSD
5. SSD detected on windows and Bios (SATA ODD= Samsung) but not my boot priority
6. I already my SSD to active (D,G), my HDD (C,E)

[image]

what should i do?

Comment: Some mainboards' UEFI won't try to find operating systems each and every boot to make everything faster. Try to look around boot settings for any option to speed up boot by skipping boot medium detection. Theoretically all you should have to do is booting the PC and shutting down again (e.g. using a live CD/DVD), then booting up again and it should be there. Also did you make sure the new drive has its primary partition set as active?

Comment: I already update it.. i already set my ssd to active

Comment: Which motherboard do you have, @GandhyOnly?

Comment: @benJephunneh did you mean this? Dell Inc. 03NKW8 (CPU)