# cannot boot from M.2 SSD

Tags: boot, ssd

I'm trying to install a Samsung 960 EVO M.2 SSD using a M.2-to-PCIe adapter (something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MYCQP38)). However, my motherboard ([ROG R4E](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/RAMPAGE_IV_EXTREME/)) did not seem to be able to recognize the drive:

1. I was NOT able to boot from the M.2 drive.
2. The M.2 drive is NOT listed in the BIOS boot menu.
3. I was able to install windows 10 onto the drive (using a bootable USB drive).
4. When booting from another drive (SATA drive & also has windows 10 installed), I was able to see the contents of the M.2 drive in file manager.

I'm pretty lost at fixing this issue. I was able to find 2 questions with similar situation ([this](https://superuser.com/questions/1282653/unable-to-setup-nvme-boot-drive-on-older-z77-motherboard) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1089892/ssd-detected-on-my-windows-but-not-detected-on-bios-boot)), so I suppose this issue is not too specific to my case. However those 2 questions are still unanswered at the moment. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Typically the allowed boot devices are SATA or USB only. Some boards have a setting to enable other boot devices.

Comment: @MichaelBay So it's basically impossible for me to boot from that M.2 drive?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have your hardware. My comment was intended only as a clue about what to look for in BIOS/UEFI settings. But it may not be possible with a PCIe adapter. An adapter for SATA should work.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks for the pointer. After changing my search terms I've found some helpful threads. I'll post an answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to boot from a M.2 drive with R4E. Sadly with old hardware it will be a longer process. The best option appears to be modding the BIOS.

Reference:

1. https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?81689-Fit-Samsung-950-pro-Pcie-M-2-on-a-Rampage-R4BE-Compability
2. https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/716439-nvme-m2-drives-on-x79/
3. https://www.win-raid.com/t871f50-Guide-How-to-get-full-NVMe-support-for-all-Systems-with-an-AMI-UEFI-BIOS.html